# Drupal 7 - change index.php as a default main page

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to work on my new website Drupal7 while I'm keeping in the hosting my old static website. So I have:
index.html (static website. I want to keep for my users)
index.php (drupal new installation)

Is there a way to set in drupal this kind of situation?
The problem, as you problably can see at this point, is that every time I'm going to a different section I'm being redirected to the .html homepage.
I mean for example the admin section is: www.mydomain.com/?q=admin instead of www.mydomain.com/index.php?q=admin
What's the easiest way to keep the html static web for my current users while I'm developing my drupal7 website in the "background"?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution finally:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]